# Podio Number to Words

Tags: javascript, podio

I'm utilizing Stephen Chapman's code on about.com titled "How to Convert Numbers to Words with JavaScript." The problem is, I can't figure out why a Podio calculated field won't accept it. I keep getting "Script syntax error: Illegal return statement." I made a fiddle of the code and tested things out, and if I make the end `return` an `alert`, it displays what I want. What doesn't Podio accept in this regard and what options are there to do this.

Context: I'm using this for automatic contract generation and I would love to have the words available. Thank you!

```js
var th = ['', 'thousand', 'million', 'billion', 'trillion'];
var dg = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four',
  'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine'
];
var tn = ['ten', 'eleven', 'twelve', 'thirteen', 'fourteen', 'fifteen', 'sixteen',
  'seventeen', 'eighteen', 'nineteen'
];
var tw = ['twenty', 'thirty', 'forty', 'fifty', 'sixty', 'seventy', 'eighty', 'ninety'];
var words = toWords(@PODIONUMBERFIELD);

function toWords(s) {
  s = s.toString();
  s = s.replace(/[\, ]/g, '');
  if (s != parseFloat(s)) return 'not a number';
  var x = s.indexOf('.');
  if (x == -1) x = s.length;
  if (x > 15) return 'too big';
  var n = s.split('');
  var str = '';
  var sk = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    if ((x - i) % 3 == 2) {
      if (n[i] == '1') {
        str += tn[Number(n[i + 1])] + ' ';
        i++;
        sk = 1;
      } else if (n[i] != 0) {
        str += tw[n[i] - 2] + ' ';
        sk = 1;
      }
    } else if (n[i] != 0) {
      str +=
        dg[n[i]] + ' ';
      if ((x - i) % 3 == 0) str += 'hundred ';
      sk = 1;
    }
    if ((x - i) % 3 == 1) {
      if (sk) str += th[(x - i - 1) / 3] + ' ';
      sk = 0;
    }
  }
  if (x != s.length) {
    var y = s.length;
    str +=
      'point ';
    for (var i = x + 1; i < y; i++) str += dg[n[i]] + ' ';
  }
  return str.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
}
```

Comment: Im betting the reason has to do with the formatting of your code, causing the function to close before the return statement, thus making the return statement illegal, and the alert statement perfectly valid.  I would use JSLint or something similar and see what it sees.  You could also use JSBeautify which might fix a rendering problem brought about my some aspect of your formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is OK with your script, you just need to re-arrange it a bit.
Here is copy/pasted version that worked great for me:

```
var th = ['', 'thousand', 'million', 'billion', 'trillion'];
var dg = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four',
  'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine'
];
var tn = ['ten', 'eleven', 'twelve', 'thirteen', 'fourteen', 'fifteen', 'sixteen',
  'seventeen', 'eighteen', 'nineteen'
];
var tw = ['twenty', 'thirty', 'forty', 'fifty', 'sixty', 'seventy', 'eighty', 'ninety'];

function toWords(s) {
  s = s.toString();
  s = s.replace(/[\, ]/g, '');
  if (s != parseFloat(s)) return 'not a number';
  var x = s.indexOf('.');
  if (x == -1) x = s.length;
  if (x > 15) return 'too big';
  var n = s.split('');
  var str = '';
  var sk = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
    if ((x - i) % 3 == 2) {
      if (n[i] == '1') {
        str += tn[Number(n[i + 1])] + ' ';
        i++;
        sk = 1;
      } else if (n[i] != 0) {
        str += tw[n[i] - 2] + ' ';
        sk = 1;
      }
    } else if (n[i] != 0) {
      str +=
        dg[n[i]] + ' ';
      if ((x - i) % 3 == 0) str += 'hundred ';
      sk = 1;
    }
    if ((x - i) % 3 == 1) {
      if (sk) str += th[(x - i - 1) / 3] + ' ';
      sk = 0;
    }
  }
  if (x != s.length) {
    var y = s.length;
    str +=
      'point ';
    for (var i = x + 1; i < y; i++) str += dg[n[i]] + ' ';
  }
  return str.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
}


var words = toWords(@Number);
words;
```